# Postgres query error: syntax error at or near ","

Tags: postgresql, node-postgres

I've seen and solved this error before but I'm really lost here as to what's wrong with my query - it seems fine to me on the surface so I'm wondering if anyone has any ideas here?

Here's the query:

```
INSERT INTO processing_queue (
  source,
  description_index,
  charge_index,
  charge_code_index,
  charge_code_label,
  cpt_code_index,
  hcpcs_code_index,
  ms_drg_code_index,
  svccd_code_index,
  ndc_code_index,
  no_of_drg_discharges_col_index,
  revenue_code_col_index,
  department_col_index,
  skip_rows,
  ignore_on,
  sheet_index
) VALUES (
  76,
  NULL,
  1,
  0,
  'Mnemonic',
  NULL,
  NULL,
  NULL,
  NULL,
  NULL,
  NULL,
  NULL,
  NULL,
  '{0, 1}',
  'Standard Price',
  0
) RETURNING *;
```

I'm using the node-postgres library here and just entering the above as a raw query with the `client.query` method.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your query.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson That's what I thought but I must be doing something wrong as I'm getting the error as above. Maybe it's to do with the library I'm using, I'll add more details to account for this.

Comment: Or you have some invisible character in your code that messes things up, have you tried to copy your query from here and executing it again?

Answer (score 0):

Confirmed that the query is not the problem and is working when I try it in psql. The error is somewhere in the thin wrapper code that I have written around node-postgres. Will try to close this as the answer is probably not so useful to anyone except me.